# How to solve error "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable" when building CNN for autoencoder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to build a CNN model for Autoencoder. My code contains 3 functions:

- `Autoencoder` contains the layers of my CNN.
- `make_autoencoder_model` initializes the model.
- `fit_model_on_cifar10` to fit the model on `cifar10`.

I encounter the error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_38/kernel:0', 'conv2d_38/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_34/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_34/beta:0', 'conv2d_39/kernel:0', 'conv2d_39/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_35/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_35/beta:0', 'dense_16/kernel:0', 'dense_16/bias:0', 'conv2d_40/kernel:0', 'conv2d_40/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_36/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_36/beta:0', 'conv2d_41/kernel:0', 'conv2d_41/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_37/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_37/beta:0', 'dense_17/kernel:0', 'dense_17/bias:0'].
```

Could you please elaborate on this error and how to fix it?

```
from keras.datasets import mnist, fashion_mnist, cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Input, Reshape, BatchNormalization, UpSampling2D
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam

##################################### Lenet-like
filters = (64, 32)
image_shape = (32, 32, 3)

class Autoencoder:
    """
    Autoencoder architecture.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Architecture settings.
        """
        # nothing to do in the init.
  
    def __call__(self, X):
        """
        Call autoencoder layers on the inputs.
        """

        # encode
        for f in filters:
            X = Conv2D(filters = f, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu')(X)
            X = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'valid')(X)
            X = BatchNormalization(axis = -1)(X)
            
        X = Flatten()(X)
        X = Dense(units = 8 * 8 * 3, activation = 'relu')(X)
        X = Reshape(target_shape = (8, 8, 3))(X)
        
        # decode
        for f in filters[::-1]:
            X = Conv2D(filters = f, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu')(X)
            X = UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(X)
            X = BatchNormalization(axis = -1)(X)
            
        X = Flatten()(X)
        X = Dense(units = np.prod(image_shape), activation = 'sigmoid')(X)     
        Y = Reshape(target_shape = image_shape)(X)

        return Y

###################################
def make_autoencoder_model():
    """
    Create and compile autoencoder keras model.
    """
    X = Input(shape = image_shape)
    Y = Autoencoder()(X)
    model = Model(inputs = X, outputs = Y)
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
                  metrics = ['accuracy'],
                  loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return model

######################################
def fit_model_on_cifar10(n_epochs = 3,
                         batch_size = 128,
                         visualization_size = 5,
                         verbose = 1):
    
    # create your model and call it on your dataset
    model = make_autoencoder_model()
    # create a Keras ImageDataGenerator to handle your dataset
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip = True)
    
    if verbose > 0:
        print(model.summary())
    (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = cifar10.load_data()

    # Be sure that your training/test data is 'float32'  and between 0 and 1 (pixel image value)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.0
    
    try:
        history = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, batch_size = batch_size),
                            epochs = n_epochs)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Training interrupted!")
    
###################################
fit_model_on_cifar10()
```

Comment: `fit()` method expects labels, when you don't provide any, it throws this error.

Comment: @Frightera In this [link](https://stackabuse.com/autoencoders-for-image-reconstruction-in-python-and-keras/), the author uses `keras.layers.Dense` and then `keras.layers.Reshape` to obtain the output image with the same dimension as the original image. This approach results in over 3 millions parameters. On the contrary, in this [link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/autoencoder-keras-tutorial), the author only uses `Conv2D`, `MaxPooling2D`, and `UpSampling2D`. I would like to ask if the addition of dense layers useful in this case?

Comment: @Frightera I have wrote a full question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66342753/is-adding-dense-or-fully-connected-layers-in-cnn-model-for-autoencoder-benefic), I hope you can visit and provide some elaboration. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a clear idea on it.